# Route OpenVPN traffic accross multiple subnets using pfSense

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, pfsense

I have two physically separate sites each with their own LAN subnets.

The primary site where the server has subnet 192.168.3.0/24. The second site has 192.168.1.0/24.

The sites are connected with a Ubiquiti wireless bridge using a separate subnet 192.168.0.0/24.

For routing I have a pfSense VM on each site. The terminals on site B can communicate with the server on site A and visa versa. Now I need to connect a remote VPN client to an OpenVPN-AS server at site B and have it communicate with the server at site A.

The graphic gives a clearer picture. (Note that the left hand Hyper-V Host should actually be Hyper-V Host 2)

[image: LAN Setup]

I am using static routes to facilitate communication between subnet 192.168.3.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 over 192.168.0.0/24.

Now my VPN client and server has an IP address from 192.168.10.0/24.

My question is where should I put what static routes to facilitate communication from the VPN client to the server and visa versa?

Comment: Sorry. The graphic shows two Hyper V hosts 1. The one on the left should be Hyper-V Host 2 which is on site B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure openvpn to push a route to 192.168.3.0/24 via the openvpn connection to the client. That can be done by setting this in the openvpn configuration:

```
client-config-dir ccd
```

Then in the `ccd` directory (relative to the configuration file) create a file with the common name of the client having this as its content:

```
iroute 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
```

The 192.168.3.0/24 server should have a default route via the Hyper-V Host 1. The Hyper-V Host 1 should have either a default route via the Hyper-V host 2, or a route for 192.168.10.0/24 via the Hyper-V host 2.